# Sylow subgroups of $A_{n}$

Tags: group-theory, sylow-theory

I get this question from my examination, I can not visualize it.

> Let $U_{p,n}$ denote the union of all $p$-sylow subgroups of the alternating group $A_{n}$ on n letters. Also let $K_{p,n}$ denote the subgroup of $A_{n}$ generated by $U_{p,n}$, and let $|K_{p,n}|$ denote the order of $K_{p,n}$.

When $n=4$, I solve this problem, but my problem is when $n>4$. For example,
what is $|K_{2,5}|$ and $|K_{3,5}|$ ?,

Comment: http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/483966/question-on-sylow-groups

Answer (score 1):

**Hint:** $K_{p,n}$ is a normal subgroup of $A_n$.

Comment: sorry ! i can not find this? please give some details.